# Move the whole document into an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

What I'm trying to do is wrap a complete website in an `iframe` without breaking any styling or javascript.

This is what I've tried:

```
var $frame = $('<iframe />').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
}).appendTo('body');

$('head').children().appendTo($frame.contents().find('head'));
$('body').children().not($frame).appendTo($frame.contents().find('body'));
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/gUJWU/3/

This works fine in Chrome.

Firefox seems to swallow the whole page.

Internet Explorer (see http://jsfiddle.net/gUJWU/3/show/) does create the `iframe`, doesn't move anything into it.

Does this approach have any chance of working cross-browser?

Comment: Why is this needed / useful? Perhaps there's a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I'm trying to create some kind of boorkmarklet which can be executed on any site to take easy control over the site's position and size

Comment: How about just altering CSS of the `<html>`? Should do the trick too, to some extent.

Comment: Well, the "Access is denied" exception is jsFiddle's fault, not yours. Try visiting your page as http://jsfiddle.net/gUJWU/3/show/ and your console should be clear...although it may not work

Comment: @MightyPork Yeah, if this approach wont work, i'll go for CSS. But I think this is prone to failure on some sites.

Comment: Well, I think "failure on some sites" is better than "failure on some browsers".

Comment: True, but I haven't given up on this approach yet (stackoverflow is my last resort).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In IE, the document isn't inferred and automatically created, so you need to actually create it before accessing it:

```
var $frame = $('<iframe />').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
}).appendTo('body');

var doc = $frame[0].contentDocument || $frame[0].contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>");
doc.close();

$('head').children().appendTo($frame.contents().find('head'));
$('body').children().not($frame).appendTo($frame.contents().find('body'));
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XAMTc/show/

This seems to work in IE8/9, and recent Firefox and Chrome, at least.

The way I figured out the problem is by `console.log`ging `$frame.contents().find('head').length`, which was 0 in IE.