# Move entire document into iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I'm adding a chat feature to a couple of our websites. The chat will connect users with people at our help desk to help them use the websites. Our help desk folks want the chat window to appear like a tab on the side of the page and slide out, rather than popping up in a new window. However, I want to allow the user to navigate around the site without losing the chat.

To do this, I've been trying to move the entire page into an iframe once the chat starts (with the chat outside the iframe), so the user can navigate around the site within the iframe without losing the chat.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259499/move-the-whole-document-into-an-iframe) to get started, and that works great visually. However, some of the javascript in the background breaks.

One of the sites is ASP.NET web forms. The other is MVC. I've been working with the web forms one first. Stuff like calling __doPostBack breaks once the page is moved into the iframe since the javascript context is left behind.

Once the user clicks on a link (a real link, not a __doPostBack) and the iframe refreshes, then everything works perfectly.

How I see it, I have a few options:

1. Copy all javascript variables from window.top into the iframe somehow. Hopefully without having to know all the variable names. I tried `this.contentWindow.__doPostBack = window.top.__doPostBack`, which works, but other variables are missing so it ultimately fails:
2. Somehow switch the iframe's context to look at the top window context, if that's even possible? Probably not.
3. Another thought was to not move the page into an iframe right away, but to wait until the page changes and then load the new page into a new iframe. But I'm not sure how to hook into that event and highjack it.
4. Something else?

These are sites for use by our employees only, so I only have to support IE11 and Chrome.

**Update:**

Thanks to LGSon for putting me on the track of using the target attribute (so I can use approach #3). Below is what I ended up doing. When I pop out the chat, I call `loadNextPageInIframe()`. I'm using jQuery here since we already use it on our site, but everything could be done without. I set the target on all links that don't already have a target pointing to another frame or _blank. I left _parent out, but I don't think we use it anyway.

I have a reference to my chat window div in a global variable called 'chatwindow'.

There still could be some cases where this doesn't work, such as if there is some javascript that sets window.location directly. If we have anything in our sites that does this, I'll have to add a way to handle it.

```
function loadNextPageInIframe() {
    var frame = $("<iframe id=\"mainframe\" name=\"mainframe\" />").css({
        position: "fixed",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        border: "none",
        display: "none"
    }).appendTo("body");

    $("form, a:not([target]), a[target=''], a[target='_top'], a[target='_self']").attr("target", "mainframe");

    var firstload = true;
    frame.load(function () {
        //Runs every time a new page in the iframe loads
        if (firstload) {
            $(frame).show();
            //Remove all elements from the top window except the iframe and chat window
            $("body").children().not(frame).not(window.top.chatwindow).remove();
            firstload = false;
        }
        //Make the browser URL and title reflect the iframe every time it loads a new page
        if (this.contentWindow && this.contentWindow.location.href && window.top.location.hostname === this.contentWindow.location.hostname && window.top.location.href !== this.contentWindow.location.href) {
            var title = this.contentDocument.title;
            document.title = title;
            if (window.top.history.replaceState) window.top.history.replaceState(null, title, this.contentWindow.location.href);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest you do the following

1. get all links
2. attach an event click handler to intercept when someone click a link
3. on click event, check if chat is in progress, and if, feed the iframe with the new link

```
var links = querySelectorAll("a");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

  links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    if (isChatInProgress()) {

      e.preventDefault();  //stop the default action

      document.getElementById("your_iframe_id").src = e.target.href;

      // anything else here, like toggle tabs etc

    }
  });    
}
```

**Update**

To handle forms I see 4 ways at the moment

1) Add an onsubmit handler to your forms

```
function formIsSubmitted(frm) {
    if (isChatInProgress()) {
        frm.target = "the iframe";
    }
    return true;
}

<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return formIsSubmitted(this)">
```

2) Add a click handler to your buttons

```
function btnClick(btn) {
    if (isChatInProgress()) {
        btn.form.target = "the iframe";
    }
    return true;
}

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonID" Text="ButtonText" 
    OnClick="Button_Click" OnClientClick="return btnClick(this);" />
```

3)  When a chat start, you iterate through each form and alter its target attribute

```
function startChat() {

  var forms = querySelectorAll("form");

  for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {

    forms[i].target = "the iframe";

  });    
}
```

4)  Override the original postback event (Src: [intercept-postback-event](http://www.pavey.me/2015/04/aspnet-intercept-postback-event.html))

```
 // get reference to original postback method before we override it  
 var __doPostBackOriginal = __doPostBack;  

 // override  
 __doPostBack = function (eventTarget, eventArgument) {

    if (isChatInProgress()) {
        theForm.target = "the iframe";
    }

   // call original postback  
   __doPostBackOriginal.call(this, eventTarget, eventArgument);  
 }
```

**Update 2**

The absolute best way to deal with this is of course to use AJAX to load both page and chat content, but that likely means a quite bigger work load if your sites aren't already use it.

If you don't want to do that, you can still use AJAX for chat and if a user were to navigate to a new page, the chat app recreate the ongoing chat window with all its content again.

Comment: The problem is that it's not only links that can move to another page. Any ASP.NET button would call __doPostBack in javascript which eventually triggers an HTTP POST.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Updated my answer. Will think this over and see if I find some other options as well.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Added a few more options for you.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Added yet another option for you.

Comment: re: your 2nd update: The other issue that complicates things is that the chat interface (the "he said she said" bits) is handled by a vendor. So that's in an iframe too. If I had full control of everything, then yes, I would have held the chat state server-side and rebuilt the chat window on each page load.

Comment: Your idea of using the form target is promising. I'm still sorting that out, but I think it might just work. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thank you! Using the target attribute did indeed do exactly what I want it to. I updated my question with the solution I used. I didn't even think of target. I rarely use iframes, so maybe that's why. I actually try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest instead of loading content to and from iframes - build the chat as an iframe and use a jQuery modal popup on the page for chat.

You can fix the jquery modal to a fixed location and page scrolling is enabled by default. You need to modify css accordingly to make the popup remains on the same location.

If you go down your current path - you will need to worry a lot about how content is moved to the iframe and it might be difficult to re-use the chat on different pages depending on the content. For example, imagine you playing a video on the page and the user clicks chat - if you load the content to the iframe - the user will lose the status on how far he has viewed, etc.

Comment: May I ask how this solution enables the users to navigate the website while they chat? ... What happens with the chat when someone goes to another page, or by modal chat popup you mean they can't?

Comment: As LGSon mentions, that doesn't address the need to keep the chat window open across page navigation. I don't see a way around using iframes if I want to do that.

Comment: I initially thought you wanted to navigate around the page - that is, scroll the page but keep the chat window open and visible. If you want to click links and still have the chat window open - then, still have the chat window as an iframe. Store chat data in database or session depending on your needs. Create a logic on whether to show or hide the chat window (maybe a boolean variable stored in session). And when links are clicked - use the logic to show / hide the chat frame and show contents from database or session.

Answer (score 0):

as per my opinion, adding the whole website as an 'I-Frame' is not a good design practice, and not a good solution for the problem. My suggestion would be:

1. Ensure that the 'Chat' application is loaded in all the pages, across your website
2. Whenever the 'Chat' is started, either establish the 'web-socket' connection or somehow, maintain the State on the Server
3. Have the configuration of the 'Chat' as 'Minimized', 'Open' etc and store them in your cookie or session storage
4. On every page load, call the 'Chat' application too. Read the Chat related configuration from sessionstorage or cookie and maintain it's state as 'Minimized' or 'Open' etc, including the X and Y position, if you want to make it as 'Floated'
5. Every time, either fetch the entire conversation from the server via Ajax or try to store and fetch from 'Local Storage' and do Ajax only for any Updates from the other party
6. Use CSS based 'Float' related properties to make it float and sit at some side.

This will ensure that your chat is available for the user and yet he can navigate all through the site.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm constrained by the fact that I don't have control over the actual chat interface (the "he said she said" bits). That part is hosted on another server and developed by a vendor. So I have to have the chat interface in an iframe, meaning the only way I can keep that iframe alive between pages is to have the main page in an iframe too.

Comment: Hi @GabrielLuci, May I know the vendor that you are using? If it's any standard Chat Service Provider and if he is providing some nice APIs, then most of the time, they should be able to generate the unique ID for the Each Chat Session. If you can get hold of that ChatSessionID, then all you need to do is that on each page, you just need to call the API with that ChatSession ID and the rest of the thing will be taken care of itself.

Comment: We're using [Computer Talk](http://computer-talk.com/)'s ICE platform. Our help desk is already using it for their phone queues. So far, most of the communication has been with project-manager type people, so it's been difficult to gauge exactly what is possible. I've just recently been put in touch with their developer, so maybe things will change once we start talking more.